# How to restrict access from a single IP per HTTP host in nginx?

Tags: security, nginx

I have an server with multiple websites each with its own host.

Is there a way in nginx to block access to `0.0.0.0/0` and allow a specific IP, let's say `1.2.3.4/32` for a specific website (specific host/domain name)?

For example:

- If a HTTP request comes with the host header `www.something-public.com` allow all.
- If a HTTP request comes with the host header `www.something-private.com` deny all and allow a specific IP address.

An additional problem that I have is that the website owners are not trusted and I want to restrict them through this rule by not allowing them to change it via config files in the website's directories (such as `.htaccess` files which override parent directory settings)

Comment: Any reason for the close votes? You people are not constructive at all

Answer (score 2):

The module [ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) has allow and deny commands you can put in your server blocks.

```
server {
  server_name www.something-public.com;
  allow all; // I think this is the default and the statement is not needed
}

server {
  server_name www.something-private.com;
  allow 192.168.1.1/32;
  deny  all;
}
```